# Cannot update data in MySQL Database using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Hello can someone assist me im failing to update the data in my mysql database

```
<?php
    require "connection.php";

    $item_name = "cheese";
    $item_code = 123;
    $item_description = "cheese is good";
    $item_unit_price  = 235;

    $mysql_query = "UPDATE Stock SET item_code = '$item_code',item_description = '$item_description',item_unit_price = '$item_unit_price' where item_name='$item_name')";

    //execute the query
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_query);


    if($conn->query($mysql_query) ===TRUE){


    echo "Stock Item Updated Successfully";


    }else{

        echo 'Error'.$mysql_query."<br>".$conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the connection?

Comment: You executed the query twice..  Procedural and object oriented style. Why?.. Also remove the last bracket

Comment: `where item_name='$item_name')"` This is the problem use `where item_name='$item_name'"`

Comment: You have a 'right' parenthesis in your query.

Comment: If any of the provided solutions worked, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be in this line :

```
$mysql_query = "UPDATE Stock SET item_code = '$item_code',item_description = 
'$item_description',item_unit_price = '$item_unit_price' where item_name='$item_name')";
```

Particularly here `')";`

You're closing a bracket when you never opened one.

Comment: Aside from the fact that this code would lead to  definite sql injection attacks,  this is not only the problem. Look at OP's code closely

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wring with your code, aside from the quite obvious SQL Injection risk.

Remove the `)` bracket from your query,

```
$mysql_query = "UPDATE Stock SET item_code = '$item_code',item_description =
'$item_description',item_unit_price = '$item_unit_price' where
item_name='$item_name')";
                    //^ remove the bracket
//execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_query);

//Executing the query again?
if($conn->query($mysql_query) ===TRUE){
```

you are executing your query twice. Remove one of the these lines:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_query);
```

Or:

```
if($conn->query($mysql_query) ===TRUE)
```

## Warning

If those variables are inputs from the user, please use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), instead, to counter the SQL Injection. Like:

```
$mysql_query = "UPDATE Stock SET item_code = ?, item_description =?, item_unit_price = ? where item_name=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($mysql_query);
$stmt->bind_param("isds", $item_code, $item_description, $item_unit_price, $item_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to remove the closing bracket,remove one of the query execution by commenting this `//$result = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_query);`out

Comment: sorry ive already commented the line out but what i was tring to say is that line should be commented out and leave the next query execution

Answer (score 0):

Try this..!!

```
<?php 
    $item_name = "cheese";
    $item_code = 123;
    $item_description = "cheese is good";
    $item_unit_price  = 235;


    $mysql_query = "UPDATE Stock SET item_code = '$item_code',item_description = '$item_description',item_unit_price = '$item_unit_price' where item_name='$item_name'";
    //execute the query
    $result = mysqli_query($conn , $mysql_query);
    if($result){
    echo "Stock Item Updated Successfully";
    }else{   
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }

    $conn->close();

?>
```